# Can [resolvconf] be made a synonym of the [resolv.conf] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think they should be made synonyms. They refer to the exact same thing even. Here's the tag wiki for [resolv.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resolv.conf):

> The resolv.conf file contains information that is read by the resolver (a set of C library routines that provide access to the Internet Domain Name System (DNS).)

Here is the tag wiki for [resolvconf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resolvconf):

> Synonym to resolv.conf.

So clearly someone thinks they are synonyms.  But, [they aren't tag synonyms](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/resolvconf/synonyms). I think [resolv.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resolv.conf) should be the main one, and [resolvconf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resolvconf) should be merged into that, given that `resolv.conf` is the filename (located in `/etc/`), not `resolvconf`. Thoughts?

Comment: Phew. I finished retagging: I went through all questions that were tagged with `resolv.conf` and which contained the string `resolvconf` and retagged as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not synonyms. [resolvconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvconf) is a software utility that manages `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Please do a bit more research than blindly trusting tag wikis. Unfortunately, tag wiki quality tends to be pretty bad. At the very least check Wikipedia and do a web search!

Answer (score 2):

[Unfortunately, I was too hasty.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5897/22222) I have now deleted the synonym I created and have recreated the [resolvconf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resolvconf) tag. I have now gone through all questions that had the  [resolv.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resolv.conf) tag and which contained the string `resolvconf` and have retagged as appropriate.

---

<del>This seems like an open and shut case, they clearly should be synonyms so I went ahead and made them synonyms.</del>

<del>The https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/resolvconf/synonyms page should now show them as synonyms. Any questions with the old `resolvconf` tag now have the `resolv.conf` one instead.</del>

<del>Thanks!</del>

Comment: This is an open and shut case: they are [clearly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvconf) NOT synonyms!

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' You're absolutely right, I'm sorry. I should have looked into it more carefully. I'm at work now, but I'l post an update later when I get the chance and see how I can fix it. This is on me, not the OP.

Comment: @terdon It's partly my fault. The point of Meta is to find issues I didn't think of. But I also should have done a quick search before posting on Meta. It's also worth noting that questions about the file [often has the resolvconf tag](http://web.archive.org/web/20211129173348/https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resolvconf) anyways, so ideally there should be something to get people to use the correct tag.

Comment: Thanks for that link, @cocomac, that will be useful. I have now deleted the synonym and I can use that link to start retagging any posts that were actually about the tool with the `resolvconf` tag.

Comment: @terdon Mind joining `/dev/chat` for a moment? I have an idea that might help

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' and cocomat, I have now gone through all questions mentioning the string `resolvconf` that were tagged with `resolv.conf` and did my best to retag correctly.

Comment: @terdon Thank you very much, very sorry for causing this. Next time I will be more careful before I come to Meta.

Comment: @cocomac you caused nothing! All you did was ask.I should have known better than to act so quickly.